# Angular 17 custom Directive rendering don't work

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I'm learning Angular.

I want to create custom directive, but doesn't work ! (it's not app for production, it's a discover app ^^)

I have no error, the project build ! But the directive don't work !

To create the directive, I use : `ng generate directive directive-name`

Can you help me to resolve my problem ?

The code :

Component - **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { POKEMONS } from './mock-pokemon-list';
import { Pokemon } from './pokemon';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    RouterOutlet,
    AppModule
  ],
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styles: [],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  pokemonList: Pokemon[] = POKEMONS;
  pokemonSelected: Pokemon|undefined;

  ngOnInit(): void {
      console.log(this.pokemonList);
  }

  selectPokemon(pokemonId: string) {
    const id: number = +pokemonId;
    const pokemon: Pokemon|undefined = this.pokemonList.find(pokemon => pokemon.id == id);
    if(pokemon) {
      console.log(`Vous avez cliqué sur le pokémon ${pokemon.name}`);
      this.pokemonSelected = pokemon;
    } else {
      console.log(`Vous avez demandé un pokémon qui n'existe pas.`);
      this.pokemonSelected = pokemon;
    }
  }
}
```

Template - **app.component.html**

```
<h1 class="center" >Liste de pokémons</h1>
<input
    #input
    (keyup.enter)="selectPokemon(input.value)"
    type="number"
/>
@if(pokemonSelected) {
    <p>Vous avez sélectionné le pokémon : {{ pokemonSelected.name }}</p>
}
@else {
    <p>Aucune correspondance.</p>
}
<div class="container" >
    <div class="row" >
@for (pokemon of pokemonList; track pokemon) {
    <div class="col s12 m4 s6">
        <div class="card horizontal" appBorderCard>
          <div class="card-image">
            <img [src]="pokemon.picture">
          </div>
          <div class="card-stacked">
            <div class="card-content">
                <p class="header">{{ pokemon.name }}</p>
                <p><small>{{ pokemon.created }}</small></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
} @empty {
    <p>Aucun élément dans la base.</p>
}
    </div>
</div>
<router-outlet />
```

The directive - **border-card.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appBorderCard]'
})
export class BorderCardDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this.setHeight(180);
    this.setBorder("#f5f5f5");
  }

  @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
    this.setBorder("#009688");
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.setBorder("#f5f5f5");
  }

  private setHeight(height: number) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.height = `${height}px`;
  }

  private setBorder(color: string) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.border = `solid 4px ${color}`;
  }

}
```

Module - **app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BorderCardDirective } from './border-card.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BorderCardDirective
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The stack :

```
Angular CLI: 17.3.2
Node: 21.6.2 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 10.5.0

Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1703.2 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         17.3.2 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   17.3.2 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          17.3.2 (cli-only)
```

Thanks for advance

Comment: Don't you get another error that says `nativeElement` is `undefined`? Normally you should wait for `ngAfterViewInit`. A better way is to use `@HostBinding('style.height.px') height?: number;` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Approach 1:

1. Please set the directive to be `standalone: true`

directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appBorderCard]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class BorderCardDirective {
...
```

2. Add the directive to the imports array of the app.component.ts

app.component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { POKEMONS } from './mock-pokemon-list';
import { Pokemon } from './pokemon';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    RouterOutlet,
    AppModule,
    BorderCardDirective,
  ],
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styles: [],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
...
```

#### Approach 2:

1. Ensure that the directive is not set to `standalone: true`

   import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

   @Directive({
   selector: '[appBorderCard]',
   })
   export class BorderCardDirective {
   ...
2. Add the directive to the declarations and exports array of the app.module.ts, only if we export the directive, it will be visible to app.component.ts

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BorderCardDirective } from './border-card.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BorderCardDirective,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    BorderCardDirective,
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

If you are using standalone app component, Please ensure you have imported the directive on the app.components imports array! Since we are adding to the imports array, we need to set `standalone: true` on the `@Directive({selector: 'some selector', standalone: true })` object of the directive file!

```
imports: [
...
BorderCardDirective,
...
]
```

If you are using modular approach, also same thing ensure `app.module.ts` has the directive added to the `declarations` array if its not standalone, or to the `imports` array  if its standalone!

If not imported then angular, will take `appBorderCard` as an HTML attribute and will not throw an error!

So, if the component/directive is standalone and used in a module, it belongs on the `imports` array, if not it belongs on the `declarations` array

---

When using the standalone approach, we are limited to using only standalone true `component/directive` with them being added to the `imports` array!

Comment: Thanks ! But I have a bug again ! The directive don't work ! I have the following error now in my terminal : TS-992011: The directive 'BorderCardDirective' appears in 'imports', but is not standalone and cannot be imported directly. It must be imported via an NgModule.

But I have not app.module.ts file in my project.

Comment: @C.Thubert we can set `standalone: true` on the directive and it will get rid of the error!

Comment: It's doesn't work (with module) ! How I say if I use standalone app component ?

Comment: @C.Thubert please share the app.component.ts, if app.module.ts exists share that also on the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257290/discussion-between-c-thubert-and-naren-murali).